# PHP Image Resize Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, memory, out

I have following PHP code that resizes my pictures to desired size:

```
/* POSTER - resize */
                $remote_file = $castImages[$name];
                $new_width  = 296;
                $new_height = 436;
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
                $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
                imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                imagejpeg($image_p, '../glumci/'.$name.' BIG.jpg', 100);
                $new_width  = 74;
                $new_height = 109;
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
                $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
                imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                imagejpeg($image_p, '../glumci/'.$name.'.jpg', 100);
                imagedestroy($image_p);
                imagedestroy($image);
```

I have around 5500 pictures to be resizes, so i run this code into the while loop and get this error from PHP:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 473956352) (tried to allocate 27263000 bytes) in D:\portal_ONLINE\UwAmp\www\inc\test.php on line 54
```

I then add in PHP script this code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

But i receive same error message..so how to fix this error so that script rename all 5500pictures not just 50 and throw this error?

Comment: Just for kicks try: `unset($image_p);` & `unset($image);`

Comment: Ok..i added code..run the script and now we will se..i will replay in about 5min to see if script is now working or not

Comment: Same error...out of memory...do you have any idea?

Comment: Try `$image_p = null, $image = null`, when you are using unset, the memory will only be freed whenever garbage collector decides

Comment: I don't see where you're writing the images back to a file. Could be you're not closing the file in whatever function handles that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from members from above replay answers i got finnaly working code:

```
/* POSTER - resize */
            $remote_file = $castImages[$name];
            $new_width  = 296;
            $new_height = 436;
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($image_p, '../glumci/'.$name.' BIG.jpg', 100);
            $image_p = null;
            $image = null;

            $new_width  = 74;
            $new_height = 109;
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
            $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
            imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
            imagejpeg($image_p, '../glumci/'.$name.'.jpg', 100);
            imagedestroy($image_p);
            imagedestroy($image);
            $image_p = null;
            $image = null;
```

Using:

```
$image_p = null;
$image = null;
```

It works now about 20minutes and script is working and not trowing error message.